# Android AOSP Upgrade

Tags: android, android-source, firmware

I've been dealing with firmware from Amlogic. The firmware consists of drivers and kernels and everything needed to build Android 6.

I got a question regarding upgrading the Android from 6 to 7 (or even later).

Can I replace the /framework /bionic /system folder with source code I got from later version of Android AOSP and compile, flash the firmware to have it working?

Thank you all in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing these Android 6 folders with respective Android 7 folders can lead to compilation errors and it is highly likely that Android boot will fail. 
To save time and headache it is advisable to use complete AOSP build for Android 7.